# Is there a way to add Pygame into a local PHP file?

Tags: php, python, pygame

Is there a method to add python pygame with images to PHP and display it in a local browser? What are the necessary requirements to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then answer is: no, it's impossible. I think — Flash is most acceptable choice for you, or Unity3D with browser plugin.

Comment: I have a pygame program with multiple images and objects, so the answer is no I'm guessing? Thanks for the answer~